# Create a button on Infopath for users to export form to PDF

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-workflow, pdf-conversion

Currently I have created a travel request form using Sharepoint 2013 and Infopath 2013 that once you submit the form, it creates a line item on the list as well as workflows to their managers for approval.

Once the managers have approved the form, on the form itself there is a field called "Approver" and "Approved On" that shows when and who have approved the form.

I want the users to be able to open the form and have a button to export the approved form to PDF. Is this possible?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move this to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com, a sister site of StackOverflow.

What I always recommend (as I work in the InfoPath / PDF business) is to attach a simple workflow to the associated forms library using a workflow tool of your choice (SharePoint Designer, Nintex Workflow, VS Workflows).

Make sure you export the relevant InfoPath status field to SharePoint so you can read the column's content in your workflow. In your workflow check if the status field is 'Approved' and if it is run a PDF Conversion action.

Now, for the big trick, the 'PDF Conversion' Action. No such action comes with SharePoint out of the box, but it is available from third parties. Google for the appropriate search terms, e.g. "Batch convert infopath using workflow" and you will find several solutions. (Disclaimer, I cannot link directly as one of the solutions you will find is one that I worked on)

Comment: thank you for your response! that seems like a bit of a challenge for me to do but I will ask the sister site as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will be interesting for you to use already existing business solution - PDF Share Forms. It is PDF form integration to SharePoint with bi-directional data synchronization (form field contents synchronizes with SharePoint columns automatically both directions). Support for archival, versioning, form flattening, workflows. Filled in form could be sent to a person, who filled it in, etc. www.pdfshareforms.com for more info

(I work for PDF Share Forms)